# How to implement simple layout: header - sidebar - content

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a simple, effective and modern way to implement the following layout for a website:
- header: 100% width 
- below header
  - sidebar with fixed width
  - content area that fills up till 100%

[image: Webdesign header sidebar content]

I've found a good example [here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_static_and_relative_positioning#Exercise_questions), but this is all based on 'em' sizing, we have quite some backgroundpixels so we rather need an example with 'px'.
We thought that we could switch easily to 'px' in that specific example, but apparently it's not that easy to get this perfect.
Thanks in advance for all the tips!

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Well Paulie_D we did attempt to code this for ourselves. I thought I've added a link but apparently that fell off. Just added the link. I can reassure you we don't want a code writing service. Just a little push in the good direction will do. Since we've felt that our code simply was not the way to go, it didn't seem very usefull with posting that. Plus I do believe that this is a question a lot of developers struggle with, so imo it's a relevant question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flex to have a sidebar on the left with a fixed width whereas the content on the right takes up the remaining space. Be aware that flex was added with CSS3 and older versions of Internet explorer may not support it (http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

```
.contentContainer {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.left {
  background-color: #ffaa00;
  min-width:200px;
}
.right {
  background-color: #00aaaa;
  flex:1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nrv5p70q/1/

However some simple googling could have solved the issue too. You may want to check this cheat sheet:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks for helping us on the way. We will try out this solution. I had never heard of this flex type of display.

Answer (score 1):

The example you are using will allow you to achieve this.

You can use a [em to px conversion](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_pxtoemconversion.asp) to convert the values from em to px. Once you have the correct values you can replace them in the css. Thus.

```
 #nav {
   margin-left: -352px; //was -22em
   margin-left: expression((-(document.getElementById("wrapper").clientWidth))+"px");
   left: 208px; //was 13em;
 }
```

Using this method will allow you to continuing w3schools tutorial which is a great way to get up to speed with html and css.